# How to pass data to children component in react native during working offline?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

please guys tell me how to pass data to react-native component offline.

Here is the example of the project I work on.
[how I want to pass data to children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLQnA.png)

It is like a learning application. I need to make it work offline but I have no idea how to store such data online and pass it to another component.

so please give me clues on how I can achieve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass data by navigation like this

```
navigation.navigate('UserDetails',{user:'Nagendra kr',userID:'97'})
```

and you can also use **Redux** instead of this , by redux you can get your stored data anywhere in your application

official page :  https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started